# How to detect which application is set as default in android?

Tags: android

I am stuck with a problem. In the past, i set an application as default launcher on my android   phone when the dialog popups up for selecting the default application and now i have forgot which application it was?

How can i detect which application has been set as default?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your aim is to do this programattically(<del>I don't think you can</del>, but I could be wrong) This would be a better fit at [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

The easiest way will probably be to go into manage applications and find all of the home screen ones, select each of them and scroll down until you see the "Clear defaults" button. The one that is not greyed out is the one that is currently set for default.

Comment: It can be done programmatically, by strategic use of `PackageManager`, though I agree that this is an end-user question and really belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @CommonsWare Would you shed a little light on doing so, please? I would appreciate it.